# how to get the selected values of Listbox in c#

Tags: c#

i had bind the listbox where datasource of listbox is list.how can i get the selected value of selected list item in listbox.my sample code as follows

```
        pdfList = attendanceDetailsPresenter.GetPredefinedDetails();
        this.lstCompanies.DataSource = pdfList;
        this.lstCompanies.DisplayMember = "CompanyName";
        this.lstCompanies.ValueMember = "CompID";

        this.lstDepartments.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
        this.lstDepartments.DataSource = pdfList;
        this.lstDepartments.DisplayMember = "DepartmentName";
        this.lstDepartments.ValueMember = "DeptID";

       if (lstCompanies.SelectedItems.Count < 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select Any one Company");
            return attendanceCalculationDetailsDataList;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lstCompanies.SelectedItems.Count; i++ )
            {
               attendanceCalculationDetailsData.CompanyID.Add(int.Parse(lstCompanies.SelectedValue.ToString()));
            }
        }
```

can anyone solve my problem please.

Comment: Why not loop `foreach(var selectedItem in lstCompanies.SelectedItems)`?

Comment: Another possible error: I don't think this will ever be true: "lstCompanies.SelectedItems.Count < 0". I believe Count can't be negative.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint within your for loop to see what is going on?

Comment: Is using Linq out of the question?

Comment: What type is your DataSource? a DataTable? or another?

Comment: @neontapir The condition reminded me of the old joke about the elevator: If two people are on the elevator and three get out, one must get in so the elevator's empty.

Comment: @Siva: what is your `pdfList` type of?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the `Count` of a list can never be less than zero. It's always `>= 0`.

Then, when you data-bind your list, the items usually are of type `DataRowView` (which you should be able to verify by debugging your application). If that is right, you should have to cast each selected item to `DataRowView` and then cast the value of its `Row` property to the type you expect.

---

I just noticed that in the following loop you're not even using the selected items, but always the `SelectedValue`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lstCompanies.SelectedItems.Count; i++ )
{
    attendanceCalculationDetailsData.CompanyID.Add(int.Parse(lstCompanies.SelectedValue.ToString()));
}
```

Try changing this to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lstCompanies.SelectedItems.Count; i++ )
{
    attendanceCalculationDetailsData.CompanyID.Add(((<WhatEverClassYouUse>)lstCompanies.SelectedItems[i]).CompanyID);
}
```

Explanation: If more than one item in the list are selected, the items are added to the `SelectedItems` collection. You can iterate these items. Each item will be an object of `DataRowView` (when data bound to a `DataTable` or `DataView`) or a class in a collection.

As you didn't tell us the type of objects returned by `GetPredefinedDetails`, I substituted it with `WhatEverClassYouUse`. Cast this to the right type.

Comment: I think the type of the item is `DataRowView` only if the DataSource type is `DataTable` or `DataView` but it seems that we're not sure what type the DataSource is.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure. Also I said that he should find that out by debugging properly.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar while try to typecast the slecteditem to DataRowview its shows an error.can you please say some other way to do this.

Comment: @Siva Did you debug your application and make sure that the items in the `SelectedItems` collection are actually of type `DataRowView`?